# Integer.parseInt couldn't convert to integer for input string "1"

Tags: java

When I run the application, it returns error codes on the console. The problem is that I can't convert from string to `int` on this line:

```
int ogrNo=Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
```

This is the method I'm using:

```
public void OgrDosyaRead() {
    try {
        File file = new File("D:\\dosya.txt");

        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while((line=buf.readLine())!= null) {
           String[] row = line.split(",");

           int No=Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
           String Name=row[1];
           String Surname=row[2];
           String lesson1=row[3];
           String lesson2=row[4];
           put(No,Name,Surname,lesson1,lesson2);

        }

          buf.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void put(int No,String Name,String Surname,String lesson1,Strşng lesson2) {
```

Error Message like this;

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at Ogrenciler.HashTable.OgrDosyaRead(HashTable.java:178)
at Ogrenciler.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:38)
```

My file, dosya.txt, looks like this:

```
1,Helen,Dobre,Lesson1,Lesson2
```

Comment: Can you try this: `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(row[0].charAt(0)));` and tell us what it says?

Comment: You may need to `trim` the input and check to make sure it's just "1"

Comment: This could be some kind of encoding/hidden character problem. How is the file encoded? I have had issues with the BOM character: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Also yes what @SterlingArcher says. Can you also try `System.out.println(row[0].length());` and tell us what it says.

Comment: what is `put(No,Name,Surname,lesson1,lesson2);` ??

Comment: @A_N_Y_R Do you think it's important? It doesn't seem so to me.

Comment: @A_N_Y_R that method isn't relevant to the question. He doesn't even reach that method in his code.

Comment: Maybe try to put row[0] in a string variable and then pass the variable see if that helps maybe its complaining about the array for some reason. @NicholasEason she

Comment: Side note: do not capitalize variable names, it makes the code harder to read because usually object types are named with capital letters in Java.

Comment: post the raw contents of `"D:\\dosya.txt`

Comment: Yes, just show us the file.

Comment: System.out.println(row[0].length()) this is ok. but it just shows how many character that I entered on console @Radiodef

Comment: I tried trim() but it is same,nothing has changed.@SterlingArcher

Comment: @nurdankaraman *"System.out.println(row[0].length()) this is ok."* What is the number that gets printed?

Comment: put(No,Name,Surname,lesson1,lesson2)  when I read on the file ,I ll send them in this method. in here.

Comment: in my text file includes for input: no: 1 , 2, 101, 103 --> output : 2 , 1 ,3 , 3 @Radiodef

Comment: **You still are NOT doing what anyone is asking!** Edit your question with the information that is requested or the question will never get answered and will probably get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code works fine:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    final String data = "1,Helen,Dobre,Lesson1,Lesson2";
    final String[] row = data.split(",");
    final int c1 = Integer.parseInt(row[0]);
    System.out.println("c1 = " + c1);
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
c1 = 1
```

#### Garbage In Garbage Out:

Your problem is something in your data, probably hidden whitespace characters of some some sort in the `1,` part of your line, or the file is encoded with a different encoding than the Java default.

Run the following on your lines:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, data.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()))));
```

This is what the output should be for the example you have given:

```
312c48656c656e2c446f6272652c4c6573736f6e312c4c6573736f6e32
```

> If you get something different then most likely the file is not
>   encoded with the same encoding that `Charset.defaultCharset()` is. You
>   will have to find what `Charset` the file is actually encoded with,
>   this depends on what application was used to create the `.txt` file.
>   If it was something Windows specific it is probably some Windows
>   default encoding, which is **not** the Java default.

Answer (score -1):

When I changed my code like this:

`int ogrNo = Integer.parseInt(row[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));`

It now works.